# Plot of a complicated function under double summation

Tags: plotting, special-functions, summation

I wrote the following inputs in mathematica to plot the following expression:

```
k1[j1_, N1_, a_] := (\[Pi]*j1)/(N1*a)
k2[j2_, N2_, a_] := (\[Pi]*j2)/(N2*a)
k3[j3_, N3_, a_] := (\[Pi]*j3)/(N3*a)
w[w0_, j1_, N1_, j2_, N2_, j3_, N3_, 
  a_] := (4*
   w0^2*(Sin[(a*(k2[j2, N2, a] + k3[j3, N3, a]))/4]^2 + 
     Sin[(a*(k3[j3, N3, a] + k1[j1, N1, a]))/4]^2 + 
     Sin[(a*(k1[j1, N1, a] + k2[j2, N2, a]))/4]^2 + 
     Sin[(a*(k2[j2, N2, a] - k3[j3, N3, a]))/4]^2 + 
     Sin[(a*(k3[j3, N3, a] - k1[j1, N1, a]))/4]^2 + 
     Sin[(a*(k1[j1, N1, a] - k2[j2, N2, a]))/4]^2))^(1/2)
q1[\[Lambda]_, \[Theta]_, \[Phi]_] := \[Pi]/\[Lambda]*Sin[\[Theta]]*
  Cos[\[Phi]]
q2[\[Lambda]_, \[Theta]_, \[Phi]_] := \[Pi]/\[Lambda]*Sin[\[Theta]]*
  Sin[\[Phi]]
q3[\[Lambda]_, \[Theta]_] := \[Pi]/\[Lambda]*(Cos[\[Theta]] - 1)
l[h_, M_, w0_, j1_, N1_, j2_, N2_, j3_, N3_, a_] := (h/(
  M*w[w0, j1, N1, j2, N2, j3, N3, a]))^(1/2)
f1[\[Nu]_, \[Mu]_, \[Eta]_, w0_, j1_, N1_, j2_, N2_, j3_, N3_, a_, 
  kb_, T_, h_, z_] := 
 Exp[-(((\[Nu] + 1/2) + (\[Mu] + 1/2) + (\[Eta] + 1/2)) h*
      w[w0, j1, N1, j2, N2, j3, N3, a])/(kb*T)]/z
  f3[\[Nu]_, \[Mu]_, \[Eta]_, w0_, j1_, N1_, j2_, N2_, j3_, N3_, 
  h_, \[Lambda]_, \[Theta]_, \[Phi]_, M_, N_, a_] := 
 NSum[N1*N2*N3*
   Exp[-q1[\[Lambda], \[Theta], \[Phi]]^2*
     l[h, M, w0, j1, N1, j2, N2, j3, N3, a]^2*1/N*
     Exp[I*a*(l1*(k2[j2, N2, a] + k3[j3, N3, a])) + (l2*(k1[j1, N1, 
            a] + k3[j3, N3, a])) + (l3*(k1[j1, N1, a] + 
           k2[j2, N2, a]))]]*
   LaguerreL[\[Nu], 
    2*q1[\[Lambda], \[Theta], \[Phi]]^2*
     l[h, M, w0, j1, N1, j2, N2, j3, N3, a]^2*1/N*
     Exp[I*a*(l1*(k2[j2, N2, a] + k3[j3, N3, a])) + (l2*(k1[j1, N1, 
            a] + k3[j3, N3, a])) + (l3*(k1[j1, N1, a] + 
           k2[j2, N2, a]))]]* 
   Exp[-q2[\[Lambda], \[Theta], \[Phi]]^2*
     l[h, M, w0, j1, N1, j2, N2, j3, N3, a]^2*1/N*
     Exp[I*a*(l1*(k2[j2, N2, a] + k3[j3, N3, a])) + (l2*(k1[j1, N1, 
            a] + k3[j3, N3, a])) + (l3*(k1[j1, N1, a] + 
           k2[j2, N2, a]))]]*
   LaguerreL[\[Mu], 
    2*q2[\[Lambda], \[Theta], \[Phi]]^2*
     l[h, M, w0, j1, N1, j2, N2, j3, N3, a]^2*1/N*
     Exp[I*a*(l1*(k2[j2, N2, a] + k3[j3, N3, a])) + (l2*(k1[j1, N1, 
            a] + k3[j3, N3, a])) + (l3*(k1[j1, N1, a] + 
           k2[j2, N2, a]))]]* 
   Exp[-q3[\[Lambda], \[Theta]]^2*
     l[h, M, w0, j1, N1, j2, N2, j3, N3, a]^2*1/N*
     Exp[I*a*(l1*(k2[j2, N2, a] + k3[j3, N3, a])) + (l2*(k1[j1, N1, 
            a] + k3[j3, N3, a])) + (l3*(k1[j1, N1, a] + 
           k2[j2, N2, a]))]]*
   LaguerreL[\[Eta], 
    2*q3[\[Lambda], \[Theta]]^2*
     l[h, M, w0, j1, N1, j2, N2, j3, N3, a]^2*1/N*
     Exp[I*a*(l1*(k2[j2, N2, a] + k3[j3, N3, a])) + (l2*(k1[j1, N1, 
            a] + k3[j3, N3, a])) + (l3*(k1[j1, N1, a] + 
           k2[j2, N2, a]))]], {l1, 0, 20}, {l2, 0, 20}, {l3, 0, 20}]
F1[\[Theta]_, \[Phi]_] := (Abs[
    Sum[f1[\[Nu], \[Mu], \[Eta], 2 \[Pi]*0.5*10^13, 1*10^7, 6*10^7, 
       1*10^7, 6*10^7, 1*10^7, 2*10^7, 0.4*10^-9, 1.3*10^-23, 300, 
       1*10^-34, 1*10^8]*
       f3[\[Nu], \[Mu], \[Eta], 2 \[Pi]*0.5*10^13, 1*10^7, 6*10^7, 
       1*10^7, 6*10^7, 1*10^7, 2*10^7, 1*10^-34, 
       0.1*10^-10, \[Theta], \[Phi], 4.48*10^-23, 8*10^22, 
       0.4*10^-9], {\[Nu], 0, 20}, {\[Mu], 0, 20}, {\[Eta], 0, 
      20}]]^2)/(Abs[
    Sum[f1[\[Nu], \[Mu], \[Eta], 2 \[Pi]*0.5*10^13, 1*10^7, 6*10^7, 
       1*10^7, 6*10^7, 1*10^7, 2*10^7, 0.4*10^-9, 1.3*10^-23, 300, 
       1*10^-34, 1*10^8]*
      f3[\[Nu], \[Mu], \[Eta], 2 \[Pi]*0.5*10^13, 1*10^7, 6*10^7, 
       1*10^7, 6*10^7, 1*10^7, 2*10^7, 1*10^-34, 0.1*10^-10, 0, 0, 
       4.48*10^-23, 8*10^22, 0.4*10^-9], {\[Nu], 0, 5}, {\[Mu], 0, 
      5}, {\[Eta], 0, 5}]]^2)

 P1 = Plot[F1[\[Theta], \[Pi]/6], {\[Theta], \[Pi]/3, 2 \[Pi]/3}, 
      PlotRange -> Full, PlotStyle -> {Red, Thick}, Axes -> True, 
     ]
```

It shows the error message `General::unfl: Underflow occurred in computation.` and after that no output has come.

I have checked the same using both the "Sum" and "NSum" command, but the same output is shown.

Further, I have checked all these functions "f1","f2"  for particular values and it gives the desired result.

I think, the problem has arisen due to the Summation over "l" in function "f3", which can cnot produce the result for set of values of the variable within the range.

Would you kindly suggest me how to change the input codes to solve the problem or any other relevant sources from where I can get some help. thanking you...

Comment: When you use decimal constants with only a few digits, like 0.5 and 0.5*10^13, these are interpreted as "machine precision" floating point numbers. If you change all those to 5/10 and 5/10*10^13 and possibly add a `WorkingPrecision->64` to your `NSum` and possibly `Plot` then your calculations may not underflow. But your calculations may be slower.  Possibly inserting a few `Simplify` in places where your calculation is very complicated and can be much simpler might help too. If it still underflows after doing this then the next thing will be to look carefully at the calculations for errors.

Comment: Even with `NSum[...,WorkingPrecision->256]; F1[1/10,Pi/6]` and not even trying to do the thousand of those `F1` to do a plot, it blows up with overflow and underflow and runs out of time for me. So I think you may need to completely rethink this calculation. I hope it works for you.

Comment: @Bill, Thanks for your kind reply...I shall check it again and inform you accordingly for further suggestion...

Comment: @Bill, I have checked the calculation and in the expression of f3[NSum ...over "l"], there is a delta function delta_{ll'}, what is missed in the above codes. Would you kindly tell me How to introduce that delta function in the expression of f3[NSum....]

Comment: This sounds like you have made progress. That is very good. Unfortunately I am not certain that I understand precisely exactly what your delta function might be. Would it be possible for you to edit your description above and show exactly where that additional function is supposed to be and then describe exactly your understanding of what that delta function is supposed to be and do.

Comment: @Bill...Okay. I shall edit the problem, posted and inform you accordingly.